# Can I programmatically list files in Images.xcassets/Something?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to list all images inside Images.xcassets/Something so that I can display them in a table list view?

I've tried:

```
NSArray *pngs = [NSBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@".png" inDirectory:@"Images.xcassets/Something"];
NSInteger count = [pngs count];
NSLog(@"%d", count);
```

... but with little success.

Thanks

Comment: Did you look inside the built app bundle to see what files are there?

Comment: Just had a look. I think my images are being compiled into a binary file: Assets.car

Comment: @ChristopherPatuzzo: Correct, therefore it's not possible to do this at runtime. What you could try, though, is create a .plist file at compile time with a run script. Then at runtime, you can read the .plist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try looking for the image files yourself - consider them to be private information in the app bundle. Instead, load them by name using `imageNamed` (no need to use the `@2x` or file extension).